# Prove $\max \cos(x)$ is $1$ and $\min \cos(x)$ is $ -1$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove $\max \cos(x)$ is $1$ and $\min \cos(x)$ is $-1$

How to prove it with only calculus and not multivariable calculus?

Please notice that this is not a homework question, but a pre-exam question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: May be, you could just draw a circle of radius 1 and remember the definition of Cos(x). Is this totally stupid ?

Comment: The ways in which you can prove this depend crucially on how define cosine. Which are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the geometric definition of cosine:  $|\cos \theta|=\frac{|\text{adj}|}{|\text{hyp}|}$.  Since the hypotenuse is the longest side in a right triangle, we find that the ratio is at a maximum when $|$adj$|=|$hyp$|$.  We can also find an instance of this happening, that is when $\theta=0$, or there is no opposite side.  Therefore $$|\cos \theta|\le 1\Longrightarrow -1\le \cos\theta\le 1$$

Comment: Ah.... I like this.... I have typed the same.... but you are a bit fast :D... Well done :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik. This is what I was trying to mean with my drawing and the definition of cosine. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici : Yes yes... I was one of the users who up voted your comment :) cheers :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik. No problem ! It is funny to see how fast people react! This is really a great site. Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

Since
$$\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x=1$$
then
$$-1\le\cos x\le 1$$
and we have
$$\cos(0)=1\quad;\quad \cos(\pi)=-1$$
Conclude.

Comment: Aren't you missing a step here you can take $cos^2x+sin^2x = 1$ but then you have to state $0 \le sin^2x \le 1$ to show $0 \le cos^2x \le 1$ before you can show $-1 \le cos x \le 1$

Comment: This step is left for you;-)

Comment: No such step is needed. Given $a^2+b^2=1$ for real $a$ and $b$, it follows immediately that $-1\le b \le 1$. Nothing needs to be known about $a$.

Comment: @SteveKass I know this but what can I do against a pedantic downvoter!

Comment: Love your avatar. Maybe we'll meet each other there. :-)

Comment: $\ddot \smile \rightarrow \uparrow^{+1}$

Answer (score 0):

Put $f(x) = \cos x - 1 $. Then $f' = - \sin x $.

$$ f' = 0 \iff \sin x = 0 \iff x = n \pi $$

and $f'' = - \cos x \implies  f''(\pi n) = 1 $ if $n$ is odd and $= -1$ if $n$ is even.

So, if $n$ is even, then $x = \pi n$ is a max and

$$ f(\pi n) \geq f(x) \implies 0 \geq \cos x - 1 \implies 1 \geq \cos x $$

Similarly, if $n$ is odd, then $x = \pi n $ is a min and hence

$$ f(x) \geq f(\pi n) \implies \cos x -1 \geq -1 -1 \implies \cos x \geq -1$$

$$ \therefore 1 \geq \cos x \geq -1 $$

Answer (score 0):

It is $\cos{(\varphi)}=\Re{({e^{i\varphi}})}$ and $|e^{i\varphi}|=1$.

$|\Re{(z)}|\leq|z|$ together with the evaluation at $0$ and $\pi$ proves your question.